# How can I change the terminal line colors by commands?

Tags: gnome-terminal, command-line, colors

I want to change my gnome-terminal lines color by using commands.

I know how change it by going to profile and clicking

Profiles" - "Profile preferences" - "color" - "background color", but I want to use commands.

Comment: Take a look at this file http://ss64.com/bash/dircolors.html and perhaps http://ss64.com/bash for all sorts of commands which may help

Answer (score 3):

In the current version of gnome-terminal you can't change background and color when starting a new terminal
It used to be with these options: `--background <color>` and `--foreground <color>`

Now you can start your terminal specifying the profile:

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile <your profile>
```

You can also edit the current profile using gconftool. for instance, to edit colors of the Default profile:

```
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/foreground_color" --type string "#EEEEEEEEECEC"
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_color" --type string "#000000000000"
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in [theme.sh](https://github.com/lemnos/theme.sh). It is a self contained script which comes with a number of prepacked themes and can be used like so:

```
theme.sh <themename>
```

Answer (score 1):

Terminal has limited options.  Install Terminator, many available options, multiple windows.  You can select background and font color. All done through preferences GUI interface.

Command Line

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

Or, get it through the Software Center.

Preferences can also be set through command line, by editing the Terminator config file.

```
cd /.config/terminator/
gedit config
```

The manpage for all available options for editing are contained in this [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man5/terminator_config.5.html).